# Call Oracle Function from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql, casting

Unsure why my code is returning an error when called from VB, however similar code in PLSQL (Oracle) isn't returning the error.

Oracle Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CUST_STRING_FROM_DB (pcustid NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    returnstring VARCHAR2(200);
    vcustomer customer%rowtype;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO vcustomer
    FROM customer
    WHERE custid = pcustid;

    returnstring := 'CustID: ' || vcustomer.custid || ' Name: ' || vcustomer.custname || ' Status: ' || vcustomer.status || ' SalesYTD: ' || vcustomer.sales_ytd;
    RETURN returnstring;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20021,'Error: Customer ID not found');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Oracle Call:

```
set serveroutput on;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line(get_cust_string_from_db(1));
end;
```

Oracle Output:

```
Anonymous Block Completed
CustID: 1 Name: Colin Smith Status: OK SalesYTD: 0
```

VB Code:

```
Private Sub GetCustString()
    Try
        Dim connOracle As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
        Dim commOracle As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
        Dim paramOracle As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter

        connOracle = CreateConnection()
        commOracle.Connection = connOracle
        commOracle.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        commOracle.CommandText = "GET_CUST_STRING_FROM_DB"

        paramOracle = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        paramOracle.ParameterName = "pcustid"
        paramOracle.DbType = DbType.Int16
        paramOracle.Value = tbGetCustStringCustID.Text
        paramOracle.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        commOracle.Parameters.Add(paramOracle)

        paramOracle = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        paramOracle.ParameterName = "pReturnValue"
        paramOracle.DbType = DbType.String
        paramOracle.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        commOracle.Parameters.Add(paramOracle)

        lbOutput.Items.Add(commOracle.Parameters.Item("pcustid").Value)
        lbOutput.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------")
        lbOutput.Items.Add("Getting Details for CustID " & tbGetCustStringCustID.Text)

        connOracle.Open()
        commOracle.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim vStr As String
        vStr = commOracle.Parameters.Item("pReturnValue").Value.ToString
        lbOutput.Items.Add(vStr)
        connOracle.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lbOutput.Items.Add(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

VB Output:

```
1
-----------------------------------------
Getting Details for CustID 1
ORA-20021: Error: Customer ID not found
```

So i'm unsure as to why this might happen.
I tried catching the value of the parameter and ensuring it was an actual integer and not a string. The CustID 1 does exist in the database and is committed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As well as specifying ths size of the return value you need to add the return value parameter first...

```
Private Sub GetCustString()
    Try
        Dim connOracle As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
        Dim commOracle As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
        Dim paramOracle As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter

        connOracle = CreateConnection()
        commOracle.Connection = connOracle
        commOracle.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        commOracle.CommandText = "GET_CUST_STRING_FROM_DB"

        paramOracle = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        paramOracle.ParameterName = "pReturnValue"
        paramOracle.DbType = DbType.String
        paramOracle.Size = 200
        paramOracle.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
        commOracle.Parameters.Add(paramOracle)

        paramOracle = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
        paramOracle.ParameterName = "pcustid"
        paramOracle.DbType = DbType.Int16
        paramOracle.Value = tbGetCustStringCustID.Text
        paramOracle.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        commOracle.Parameters.Add(paramOracle)

        lbOutput.Items.Add(commOracle.Parameters.Item("pcustid").Value)
        lbOutput.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------")
        lbOutput.Items.Add("Getting Details for CustID " & tbGetCustStringCustID.Text)

        connOracle.Open()
        commOracle.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim vStr As String
        vStr = commOracle.Parameters.Item("pReturnValue").Value.ToString
        lbOutput.Items.Add(vStr)
        connOracle.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        lbOutput.Items.Add(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Ciarán! Order does matter. I just learned something I wish I never had to know. Relieved...but a little sad too.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the (max) size of return value, i.e.

```
paramOracle.Size = 200
```