# in vb.net, how to execute a oracle database function with output parameter

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g

in windows application using vb.net , how to execute oracle database function with output parameter.please help me in that thank you in advance.

here i am using VB.NET, oracle 10g

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have tagged your question as vb.net and oracle.

Since I can't just comment quite yet, see [Call Oracle Function from Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453347/call-oracle-function-from-visual-basic) for an answer to your issue, which should get you started at least.